# Linux alternative to Windows Home Server Backup

Tags: linux, backup, windows-home-server

I love the backup capabilities of Windows Home Server, but that's about the only feature of it that I use.

Does anyone know of any Linux-based services that will allow me to backup client PCs in a similar way to WHS (an image style backup, only backing up what's changed) and 
lets me restore in a similar way - by booting from a CD and then reimaging the PC over the network?

Answer (score 1):

I use Amanada.  For bare box recover look at Mondo which can generate bootable media.  The two together provide a very flexible backup and recovery setup.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but have seen references to [Amahi](http://www.amahi.org/) as a managed home server designed to be install and forget (almost seems anti Linux to me, but hey ho)

Comment: After the announcement of Drive Extender being removed from WHS, I installed Amahi in a virtual environment.  The Greyhole technology looks very promissing as a replacement for DE, but there isn't any comparable backup solution included.  I haven't researched enough yet to find something suitable to run under Amahi, but the server is pretty solid, if not nearly as friendly as WHS.